# "He even SPRUNG for the good stuff"?

Tags: meaning

In the movie "The Mechanic" (2011) I came across the following piece of conversation:

> "Liquor fairy paid me a visit last night. Left me a big old bottle of scotch."

(This part is pretty understandable as the movie hero had left his interlocutor a bottle of alcohol, "a fairy" because the interlocutor had been sleeping at the time of delivery.)

But the continuation:

> "He even **sprung** for the good stuff."

I can't understand this.

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain.

Comment: It's one of many "elevating/uplifting" metaphors for ***coming up with*** or *putting up the money, coughing [up] for, stumping up for* something (often, *expensive*).

Answer (score 5):

“Spring for” is informal English (mostly US) meaning “pay money for”, with the nuance that the subject is paying more than what one might expect. This can be because the thing is expensive in absolute terms, or because cheaper alternatives are available, or because the subject is paying for other people (often in addition to himself).

It's common to say that one *springs for* a more expensive model. “He even sprung for the good stuff” means that not only did the unnamed person buy scotch for the narrator, but that person even brought good scotch, which presumably costs more. *Spring for* can have a connotation that the person is [indulging](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indulge) in a luxury.

Some dictionaries (for example the [Oxford Advanced American Dictionary](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/spring+for#spring_2__93) list *spring for* as specifically meaning paying for someone else. But this is in fact not always the case, and I think it is not the primary meaning of the expression — *spring for* only connotes paying for someone else because the person is paying more than the minimum (which would be their share). For example the [Camdbridge American English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/spring-for-something?q=spring+for) gives the example phrase “To increase the radio's performance, spring for a powered antenna”: a powered antenna costs more than an ordinary antenna, but gives better performance.

Comment: +1 for "_Spring for_ can have a connotation that the person is indulging in a luxury." I don't "spring for" my electric bill, but I might "spring for" my roommate's portion of it, if he's low on funds. Or, I might "spring for" a new sweater – particularly if our power gets shut off ;^)

Answer (score 3):

"To spring for" something is an informal/slang phrase meaning to pay for or buy something.

e.g. "don’t spring for the album until you’ve heard it" means don't pay for or buy the album until you've heard it.

So "he even sprung for the good stuff" is indicating that the movie hero bought a good quality bottle of scotch.

Comment: Note also that standard English has the verb triple spring/sprang/sprung, but it's not uncommon in some dialects to say instead spring/sprung/sprung (or sing/sung/sung, ring/rung/rung, etc.)

Comment: This appears to be chiefly US usage. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/spring) tags it as such (Def. #5). Interestingly enough, their British English edition lists [17 verb definitions of _spring_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spring), but this "buy something for someone" meaning isn't included among them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is proficient. May I associate "to spring for something" with "to reach for something"? Would that seem correct? Or fetch something would be more correct?

Comment: @ukna1 I would say that neither of those associations is correct.  I'm not sure how you've managed to reach that conclusion from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should say, "he SPRANG for the good stuff." That's in the past tense.

The past participle construction is "he HAS sprung for the good stuff."

Both of these are past forms of "spring," which literally means to "jump" or "reach," but figuratively means "pay." (As in, to "spring" for the check or bill.)